# How to pronounce "Pugh"?

Tags: pronunciation

Does [Bill Pugh's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Pugh) last name rhyme with 'tug', 'few', or something else?

Comment: My guess is few

Comment: http://www.pronouncenames.com/pronounce/pugh

Comment: *If the human brain was so simple that we could understand it, we would be so simple that we couldn't.* --Emerson Pugh 
Read more at http://quotes.dictionary.com/despite_many_assertions_to_the_contrary_the_brain#CIdB3z8l1GylxIo4.99

Comment: Happy to help. Keep coming back to ELU.

Comment: I think pronunciation of proper names is Off Topic. FWIW, both the ***Pugh's*** I ever knew pronounced their names to rhyme with *knew, few*. They probably wouldn't have liked anyone (Americans?) rhyming their names with *Winnie the **Pooh***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Which is funny because that was my first thought when I read your *knew and few,*  since the Americans I know pronounce *knew* more like *Pooh,* while we do pronounce *Pugh* like *few.*  :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Americans pronounce *knew* and *dew* like *Pooh* (well, some Americans, I pronounce *dew* like *Pooh* but *knew* like *few*), but they pronounce *few* and *Pugh* and *mew* like *few*. It depends on the initial consonant .

Comment: @Peter: I assumed there weren't any Anglophones for whom *moo* and *mew* would be homophones, but I didn't realise there was a "rule" based on *the consonant before **ew***. Is that General Reference - in which case could you post a link to it? If not, I rather think I'd like to ask the question here just so we *can* have a reference. (Not to mention which, in the case of *pew/Pooh/Pugh*, that rule wouldn't actually help! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There's a discussion of this under [yod dropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping) in Wikipedia. The short answer is that almost all Americans retain the /j/ in initial /pju/, /bju/, /kju/, /gju/, /fju/, /vju/, /mju/, /hju/ (although some New Yorkers drop the /h/ in words with initial /hju/). For all other initial combinations, the /j/ is dropped by some large fraction of (I'd guess most, but I don't have any real data) Americans. So that means it sounds very funny to me when Brits add an unwarranted /j/ to *kudos*.

Comment: @Peter: Damn right "yod dropping" appears "complicated"! I'm reasonably familiar with the Welsh accent, but I can't see how it's part of any (putative) distinction between *yew/you* as claimed there. All ***I*** hear is that Welsh speakers habitually shorten the second (/u/) component of the diphthong /ɪu/. But I'm no phonologist, obviously - mostly I seem not to even *hear* sound differences that have little or no semantic significance.

Comment: Is that new-clear or noo-clear that I hear? No one else in the world seem to drop yods, or do they?

Comment: @Kris: according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping). almost every dialect of English except  Welsh drops some yods (like the one in *rude*), and some regional dialects in England drop even more yods than Americans do. [Listen](http://www.forvo.com/word/nuclear/#en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pugh is a Welsh name derived from 'ap Hugh' meaning son of Hugh and is therefore pronounced 'Pew' not 'Poo'. A traditional Welsh spelling would actually be Puw as Huw is the Welsh form of Hugh. [Pugh/Puw](http://www.meaning-of-names.com/welsh-names/puw.asp)

Comment: Something in support of the claim can make this an "answer".

Comment: Added link and expanded answer